# Easiest way to achieve spinning line laser

Tags: laser

I'm looking to use spinning line lasers and have been thinking for a while now how to achieve it in a cost effective way.
The result I'm going after is as in Valve Lighthouse boxes, although not for the same purpose. 
Possibly I could use similar mechanics as in barcode scanners.
Reason I'm asking here is because I'm looking for an off the shelf solution, as much as possible at least, as I have low confidence that I will be able to manufacture such a thing myself.

*Edit*

As "off the shelf solutions" are offtopic, I would rather like to know how to practically build a reliable spinning mirror myself. I imagine I could use a 3D printed 45 degree slope with a mirror on top and mount it on a dc motor. What would I use as material for the mirror? How could I make it as precise as possible?

Comment: Spinning in what direction? Why not get a motor?

Comment: vertical laser and central balanced spinning 45 deg mirror comes to mind , all perfectly aligned within a floating gimbal with fluidic or magnetic dampening.

Comment: Can you explain what a spinning line laser is? Is it similar to a laser level such as one might find in a hardware store? https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00ME77KCI/

Comment: *"I'm looking for an off the shelf solution"*. Unfortunately, shopping questions are off topic.

Comment: @mkeith Yes, actually, the same concept, except that I need it to be bare basics. So a DC motor with 45 deg mirror as mentioned by Tony Stewart would work best. If I would have to produce the spinning mirror myself, how would I go best about it?

Comment: You need to buy one.  That's how you would meet your needs

Comment: @RobotRock, that wouldn't be electrical engineering.

Comment: I got 1 1/2 sentences in and gave up.  Closing as *unclear*.  "Spinning line laser" is very ambiguous, and I have no idea what a "Valve Lighthouse box" is supposed to be.  *Screw this.*

Comment: @OlinLathrop Whatever internethero

Comment: @RobotRock This isn't really electrical engineering, there is a reason that laser levels are super expensive, even being a thousandths of a degree off will add up several feet away from the level. You would spend more money and time trying to conjure one up than buying one. But if its the project your after then go for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your search problem is primarily one of terminology, what you need to search for is a **polygon** mirror scanner.

For a one-off they can be salvaged from a old (true) laser printer, along with the driver board. Most modern laser-class printers are actually LED printers and do not have a laser scanner. Some of the old HP Laserjet types do.

You can easily buy the scanner as a spare part, but they are not all that cheap and you would still need to find a way to drive the motor.

Check out the openexposer project on github.

Edit: Actually they seem to be relatively cheaply available from Asia as spare parts and the motor is generally on the driver board but you would still have to deal with the board interface.